# regex to match a word and everything after it?

Tags: python, regex

I need to dump some http data as a string from the http packet which i have in string format am trying to use the regular expression below to match 'data:'and everything after it,Its not working . I am new to regex and python

```
>>>import re
>>>pat=re.compile(r'(?:/bdata:/b)?\w$')
>>>string=" dnfhndkn data: ndknfdjoj pop"
>>>res=re.match(pat,string)
>>>print res
   None
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) matches only at the beginning of the string. Use [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) to match at any position. (See [`search()` vs. `match()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match))

```
>>> import re
>>> pat = re.compile(r'(?:/bdata:/b)?\w$')
>>> string = " dnfhndkn data: ndknfdjoj pop"
>>> res = re.search(pat,string)
>>> res
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0000000002838100>
>>> res.group()
'p'
```

To match everything, you need to change `\w` with `.*`. Also remove `/b`.

```
>>> import re
>>> pat = re.compile(r'(?:data:).*$')
>>> string = " dnfhndkn data: ndknfdjoj pop"
>>> res = re.search(pat,string)
>>> print res.group()
data: ndknfdjoj pop
```

Comment: Note that `'/b' != '\b'`.

Comment: Also, I don't think even `'\b'` will work without some adjustment, because the word boundary is between `'data'` and `':'`

Comment: @jonrsharpe, Yes, I agree with that. That's why I updated the answer to suggest to remove `/b`.

Comment: thanks :) btw we do not need '/b' cuz anything between '()' is considered as a group ??

Comment: @user2542967, Because `/b` matches `/` and `b` literally, not because it is inside a `()`.

Answer (score 5):

No need for a regular expression here. You can just slice the string:

```
>>> string
' dnfhndkn data: ndknfdjoj pop'
>>> string.index('data')
10
>>> string[string.index('data'):]
'data: ndknfdjoj pop'
```

[`str.index('data')`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.index) returns the point in the string where the substring `data` is found. The slice from this position to the end `string[10:]` gives you the part of the string you are interested in.

By the way, `string` is a potentially problematic variable name if you are planning on using the [`string` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#module-string) at any point...

Answer (score 1):

you can just do:

```
string.split("data:")[1]
```

assuming "data:" appears only once in each string